# Bash script not executing mongod command

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, path

I have a simple bash script to run mongodb:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mongod --dbpath data/db
echo "Mongo is running!"
```

In the terminal, I execute:

> . ./mongo.sh

I am sure that the directory is correct and that I have already CHMOD my permissions to 751 so I should be able to execute the script. But instead I get this error:

```
2016-08-28T16:15:15.311-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-08-28T16:15:15.311-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-08-28T16:15:15.311-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-08-28T16:15:15.311-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-08-28T16:15:15.311-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-08-28T16:15:15.311-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "data/db" } }
2016-08-28T16:15:15.312-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory data/db not found., terminating
2016-08-28T16:15:15.312-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
Mongo is running!
```

When I run "mongod --dbpath data/db" in a shell window the command executes without a problem so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this may have to do with the "sub-process" that shell scripts execute in? But I'm really not sure I have never wrote bash scripts before...

Comment: I suggest to add full path to data/db.

Comment: Yes! That worked... I cant believe I didn't think of that. Please add as answer if you want the points otherwise thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add full path to `data/db`.